# Как вызвать метод класса из другого метода

Tags: javascript

Допустим есть такая структура:

```
class Animal { 
 sayHi(){
  console.log('hi')
 } 
 makeHi(){
   sayHi()
  }
 }
new Animal().makeHi()
```

> sayHi is not defined

Как исправить ?

Comment: `this.sayHi()`.

Comment: @smellyshovel это первое что я попробовал, не работает так

Comment: @NikitaR. ответил предыдущему.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/88wp34pl70